# Does "wired" mean nervous or connected in this title?

Tags: meaning-in-context

"British ambassador, now target of Trump’s ire, has D.C. wired"

From [politico.com](https://www.politico.com/story/2019/07/09/british-ambassador-donald-trump-1404601)

Comment: In this case I read it to mean nervous. I doesn't really make sense to substitute "connected"

Answer (score 3):

**"British ambassador, now target of Trump’s ire, has D.C. wired"**

The old fashioned idiom would be "on edge"

"British ambassador, now target of Trump’s ire, has D.C. "on edge"

Meaning excited (not in a nice way), nervous, anxious

> wired adjective (EXCITED) informal (uk also wired up) nervous or excited, for example because of a future event, or because you have drunk coffee or taken drugs: [Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/wired)
>
> I was totally wired before the interview.
>
> I find that eating something can help if I'm too wired on caffeine.
>
> Sometimes, for no apparent reason, all the children may become wired up.

Comment: Where did that derive from?

Comment: @marcellothearcane; I don't know for sure but I can hazard a guess. People who use drug,; particularity addicts when deprived of drugs make quick erratic movements and can go into spasm. People receiving an electric shock also do the same.

Comment: Etymonline is interesting, if a little unhelpful: https://www.etymonline.com/word/wired#etymonline_v_44201

Comment: Was D.C on edge or British ambassador on edge?